# On the Day Of Judgement, can I be a righteous person and when I go to cross al-sirat, I fall?

Tags: day-of-judgement

This question has been causing me to think about it, I tried to research about the topic, but I couldn’t find any results. Please help.

Comment: There are actually two bridges (sirat) that humans will be asked to cross. The second of these only the believers will be asked to cross.

Comment: oh, i always thought that the believers and the non believers will walk on the same one, and whoever falls, ends up in hell ( of course it depends on whether Allah SWT helps us or not)

Comment: You can also refer to: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/47806/what-are-the-two-bridges-that-act-as-a-test-on-judgement-day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, al-sirat doesnt depends on your abilities that you have on Earth :). Allah will help good people and they will pass quickly(as my teachers say) and sinner people will be like a turtle, they won't manage to pass and nobody will help them.